# How to run Selenium scripts with a mocked time zone?

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, timezone

I want to run Selenium scripts (C#) with a mocked time zone.

Setting the system time is not an option here, as the server I test with these scripts runs on the same machine and I don't want to change the server's time zone as well. Is there any way to set only the browser's time zone by selenium?

Comment: I don't think that browsers expose in their options/preferences/profiles a way to arbitrarily set the time zone to something else than what the OS is set to. So I'd expect solutions to depend on the OS. What OS runs your browser?

Comment: you can mock the date object (JS) and inject it using javascricptExecutor

Comment: @ErkiM. Sounds promising, I'll try that